# Multiple Conditionals and globbing in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting, glob

So have I got this right?  In Bash, I can use globbing to test strings for patterns if I use double-brackets around the condition:

```
if [[ $var = abc* ]]
```

and I can test for multiple conditions if I use single brackets:

```
if [ $var = abc123 -o $var = abc456 ]
```

but there's no way I can do both together?

I'm using Bash v3.0, so it doesn't recognize regex's or the =~ operator.

Comment: `if [[ "$MACHTYPE" == "x86_64--netbsd" && "$OSTYPE" == "netbsd" ]]` works perfectly fine in my bashrc.

Comment: `=~` should be available in 3.0.

Comment: @chepner - After checking, you're right.  I don't know why I thought it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `-o` is deprecated by the POSIX standard. For POSIX compatibility, use two separate `test` commands:

```
if [ "$var" = abc123 ] || [ "$var" = abc456 ]
```

In `bash`, you can do the same, with either `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]` commands, or use `||` inside a `[[ ... ]]` command:

```
if [ "$var" = abc123 ] || [ "$var" = abc456 ]  # POSIX compatible

# No reason to use either of the next three, but the syntax is valid
if [[ "$var" = abc123 ]] || [ "$var" = abc456 ]
if [ "$var" = abc123 ] || [[ "$var" = abc456 ]]
if [[ "$var" = abc123 ]] || [[ "$var" = abc456 ]]

if [[ "$var" = abc123 || "$var" = abc456 ]]    # Preferred for bash
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'd just found another Q here where the use of the double-pipe was suggested, and was coming back here to answer my own question, but you beat me to it.

Comment: The `-o` option has been around for a long time. Why not use it? Is it strictly necessary to produce POSIX-compliant scripts nowadays? Just a thought.

Comment: There are parsing ambiguities involved with `-o`; the POSIX spec itself deprecates its use and suggests `[ ...] || [ ... ]` in its place. If you aren't concerned with POSIX compatibility, `[[ ... || ... ]]` is superior in terms of its handling of null variables and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if [[ $var == "abc"* ]]
```

I found answer there http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1118003

Comment: Thanks, but I already had single-condition tests working in double brackets.  The simplest way is to remove quotes altogether.